# How can I keep the serial address consistent on my Arduino Uno (Mac OSX)?

Tags: macos, arduino

On a Mac, Arduino devices like the Uno are identified as network interfaces, and are assigned a serial address of the form /dev/tty.usbmodem*.  I am using a Java program that requires me to save in my file the address of the serial device I want to use.  However, when I reboot my computer with the identical device connected, it sometimes assign the device a different serial address.  Is there any way to specify either on my computer or my Arduino board that a specific board needs to always be assigned to the same serial address?

(Additionally, I can't simply use the address of whatever the first serial device connected to the system is, as I have multiple Arduino boards that do not stay in a consistent order when I list serial devices).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by having a program (in my case C#) loop over all the available ports and send a handshake message ("HELLO').

Then On the arduino side I make my sketch respond with a "HELLO FROM ARDUINO01" message.
My program on the PC stops when if finds the arduino it is looking for and continues using that port.

Comment: Ohh, no.  My serial device responds to the command HELLO by releasing hell on earth.  Make sure not to plug into your computer :)

Comment: Maybe this could be fixed by having the Arduino broadcast 'I AM 1' every second.  The host computer would just open the serial port and listen.  If it hears 'I AM 1', it responds 'HELLO' which ends the announcement mode.